# Load heavy SVG (around 10k vector object) into canvas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, canvas, fabricjs

We want to load heavy SVG's JSON object (around 10k vector object) into the canvas. Right now we are able to do but the process is lagging very much due to numbers of vector object in canvas. Below is the flow we are following

1. Load SVG which is saved in the database as the JSON object in the
   canvas
2. So the user can edit.
3. Convert the canvas in SVG.
4. Save the edited SVG in the database as the JSON object.

This is working fine when vector objects are less in number (less than 2K), but when the number goes high, system start lagging and some it crashed. We want to manage around 15k - 20k vector objects. We are using fabricjs for this.

->

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the last version of fabricjs (2.3). It use a canvas for caching the path. This how the path is drawed only when you resize it.